# Manual swipe using slickjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Using Slick how can I use the swipe event listeners to change the swipe behavior?

I'm trying to insert a slider inside a slider and that's why I need to write the swipe behavior. I want to leverage the event but not use the actual swiping.

I tried using `swipe: false` and `swipe` event but without the swipe flag none of the events are used.

`$images.on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // get current slide, move accordingly 
});`

Is there a way to do this? Or should I try to rewrite the swipe or use Hammer?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to: 
- set `swipe` option to `false`
- write your own custom swipe completion handler.

*I'm sure you've figured something out by now (2.5 years later).*